# Trying to make a slider but i keep getting incompatible types

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to make a Slider in Delphi, but I keep getting errors:

> Incompatible types 'TPoint' and 'TPointF'
>
> Incompatible types 'Integer' and 'Single'
>
> Incompatible types 'Integer' and 'Extended'

I don't know why I'm getting these errors.

```
procedure TForm1.FormTouch(Sender: TObject; const Touches: TTouches; const Action: TTouchAction);
var
  T:TTouch;
  F: TfmxObject;
  M: TrectF;
  L: TLine;
  R: TRoundRect;
  P: TPoint;
begin
  for T in Touches do begin
    case Action of
      TTouchAction.down,
      TTouchAction.Move:
        for F in Children do
          if F is Tlayout then begin
            M := TLayout(F).AbsoluteRect;
            M.Inflate(0, -10);
            if M.Contains(T.Location) then begin
              L := TLine(TLayout(F).Children[0]);
              R := TRoundRect(L.Children[0]);
              P := TLayout(F).AbsoluteToLocal(T.Location);
              P.X := R.Position.X;
              P.Y := P.Y - 10 - R.Height * 0.5;
              R.Position.Point := P;
            end;
          end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[`TPoint`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Types.TPoint) has `Integer` fields, and [`TPointF`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Types.TPointF) has `Single` (floating point) fields.

You need to use one or the other, or convert between `Integer`/`Single`.

Answer (score 2):

In `P := TLayout(F).AbsoluteToLocal(T.Location);`, you are trying to assign a [`TPointF`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Types.TPointF) to a [`TPoint`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Types.TPoint), but they are completely different types that are not assignment-compatible with each other. `TPointF` holds `Single`s whereas `TPoint` holds `Integer`s instead.

In `P.X := R.Position.X;`, you are trying to assign a `Single` to an `Integer`. That assignment is not allowed without a type-cast.

In `P.Y := P.Y - 10 - R.Height * 0.5;`, you are trying to assign an `Extended` to an `Integer`. That assignment is not allowed without a type-cast.

That said, [`TLayout.AbsoluteToLocal()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.AbsoluteToLocal) returns a `TPointF`, and [`R.Position.Point`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TPosition.Point) wants a `TPointF`, so your `P` variable should be declared as `TPointF` instead of `TPoint`.  That should solve all 3 of your errors.

Comment: when i click on the slider i keep getting Access Violation at address 00A021FD in module 'BOLT.exe' Read of address 00000000.

Comment: That means a `nil` pointer is being accessed at runtime. You need to debug your code to find out where it is. That is a completely different issue than the compiler errors you originally asked about. If you need further help with the AV, post it as a new question.